# How to open Chrome with a specific profile using Selenium

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver, automated-tests

I’m trying to open a youtube page with my Chrome profile so I don’t have to sign in and do the MFA which ruins the automation. This is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/'
 
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
 
options.add_argument(r"C:\Users\User01\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\profile 1")
 
options.add_argument(r'--profile-directory=Profile 1')
 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
 
driver.get(url)
```

According to multiple sources online this code should do that but it is still opening the test browser.

I’ve tried multiple solutions online asked a few AI tools and no luck so far

Answer (score 1):

In my case this worked fine.

```
ons = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

ons.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\{user_name}\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\profile1")
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not your case, but anyway. Ones I was fighting with one allure issue very long. But appeared, it was not understanding a space in the path to the project dir. I noticed in your path '\User Data' with the spaces. Try to move it somewhere to the folder without any spaces in its name, e.g. UserData or any other folder.

I am not guarantee it will solve your case, but according to your question you seems like tried all almost, so who knows if the reason is not in your setup but in something else.